# Filtering union of strings with suffix

Tags: typescript

I have this line of code:

```ts
type RouterQuery = keyof AppRouter['_def']['queries'];
```

Which will give me this type:

```ts
type RouterQuery = "healthz" | "post.all" | "post.byId" | "category.all" | "category.byId" | "course.all" | "course.featured"
```

I'm trying to get only strings that have an '.all' postfix.

The desired type would be:

```ts
type RouterQueryAll = "post.all" | "category.all" | "course.all"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

```ts
type RouterQueryAll = Extract<RouterQuery, `${string}.all`>
```

Using [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union), you can ‘filter’/extract types from a union that are assignable to another type. `` `${string}.all` `` is an example of a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) that matches all strings ending in `.all`.